# Flask REST - UPDATE user model

Tags: rest, flask, sqlalchemy

i am building a REST api with JWT authorization abstracting the user model. So these are some of the functions I define in my user model definition:

```
def save_to_db(self):
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()

def update_db(self):
    db.session.commit()

def delete_from_db(self):
    db.session.delete(self)
    db.session.commit()
```

and these are the methods:

```
@jwt_required()
    def get(self):
        user = UserModel.find_by_email(current_identity.email)
        if user:
            return user.json(), 200
        return {'message': 'User not found'}, 400

    def post(self):
        data = UserRegister.parser.parse_args()

        if UserModel.find_by_email(data['email']):
            return {"message": "User already exists"}, 400

        user = UserModel(**data)
        user.save_to_db()

        return user.json(), 200

    @jwt_required()
    def put(self):
        user = UserModel.find_by_email(current_identity.email)
        if user:
            data = UserRegister.parser.parse_args()
            try:
                user = UserModel(**data)
                user.update_db()
                return user.json(), 200
            except:
                return {'message': 'An error ocurred while inserting user data.'}, 400
```

Everything is working except the PUT method. It does not store the actual value in the database, I am wondering why.

Comment: Does it return the error message instead?

Comment: You create a new `UserModel` object, yet you call `update_db()`, which does not add the created object to the session, and so there's nothing to commit. You're probably interested in `Session.merge()`, if the PUT endpoint is supposed to be able to modify existing objects and you wish to use the ORM.

Comment: No error message @SuperShoot!